# Minimum bits required for two's complement number representation

Tags: twos-complement

I need to find out that how can we represent `-1` and `-3` in minimum number of bits in Two's complement number system. I calculated the answer `1` and `111` but the answers seem to be incorrect. I would be very thankful if I can get some help. Thanks

Comment: I have the answer but its not coming right. Yes its homework..

Comment: Sounds like a job for cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sounds a bit simple for cstheory.stackexchange.com to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the formula you're probably already familiar with: `N' = 2^n - N`.
Where n is number of bits, **N'** is the decimal representation of **-N**'s complement, and `N` is the cardinal number.
For example, `short int x = -6` is going to be `N' = 2^8 - 6 = 250` when converted to `unsigned short int`.

Now, with this formula, you can get `n = log(N+N')` (log of base 2).

**Edit:**

I was more focused on just the number of bits. Now I've re-read your question...
Let me give you an answer: 
You need at least two bits to represent 3 and you need that one extra bit to represent *signness*, which means you need at least 3 bits to represent -3. Same goes for 1. Having that in mind, [011] = 3, take the complement of one (inverting bits) => [100] and add 1 => [101] = -3. 
As for the -1, you do the same. [01] = 1, invert the bits => [10] => add one => [11] = -1.

That's it, I think...

Answer (score 0):

`-1` can be represented by `1` and `-3` can be represented by `101` (-4 + 1).

`111` is equal to decimal `-1` (-4 + 2 + 1).