# Finding n bit length 2s complement representation of a number

Tags: c, binary, bitwise-operators, twos-complement

I am writing a function with parameters:

```
int nbit2s(long int x, long int n){

}
```

I am looking to take in 64 bit number x, and find if a 2 bit representation of *n* bit length is possible. I am however restricted to using only bitwise operators and excluded from using operators such as >= <=, and conditional statements

For example, nbit2s(5,3) returns 0 because the representation is impossible.

I'm not looking for any code but just for ideas, so far my idea has been:

1. Take in number n and convert it to it's binary representation.
2. Left Shift the binary representation 64-n times to get MSB and store that in a variable shift
   3.Shift to the right 64-n to get leading bit and store in shift
3. XOR original number with W, if 1 then TRUE, 0 then FALSE.

I feel like this is along the right lines, but if someone could explain perhaps a better way to do it or any mistakes i may have made, that would be great.

Comment: `long int x` may only be 32-bit.  Recommend `long long` or `uint64_t`.

Comment: I was under the impression that long int was 64 bit on a mac machine and kept as 32 bit on windows machines.

Comment: I feel you're doing the same course: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122636/finding-how-many-bits-it-takes-to-represent-a-2s-complement-using-only-bitwise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204075/minimum-bits-required-for-twos-complement-number-representation

Comment: I believe this is the answer you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/16105238/1772838

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you would like to determine if the integer `x` can be represented as a binary number with `n` or less bits.

An easy way to test for this is to use the bitwise AND operator to mask out all bits above a maximum value, and then see if the masked integer is the same as the original.

Example:

```
bool nbit2s(uint64_t x, int n) {
    return (x & (1ULL << n) - 1) == x;
}
```

Comment: `1 << n` may not shift 64 bits as the `int 1` may be narrow.  Better to use `1ULL << n` or the like

Comment: This works for unsigned numbers only. The question includes negative ones.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for positive numbers would be to just shift right by `n`. If it's still non-zero, then it needs more than `n` bits to represent it.

But since the argument is signed and you're talking about 2 complement representation, you'll probably have to cast it as unsigned representation to avoid sign extension.